# OpenGL with OpenTK: how to replace not working GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray)?

Tags: opengl

I tried to draw banch of lines(vary basic and simplest thing) using VBO as folloiwng:

```
struct VertexColor
{
        public Vector2d vertex;
        public uint color;
       //...
}
//...
Draw(){
    GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray);
    GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);

    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, lineVbo.VboID);
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, lineVbo.EboID);

    GL.VertexPointer(2, VertexPointerType.Double, BlittableValueType.StrideOf(lineList.ToArray()), 0);

    GL.ColorPointer(4, ColorPointerType.UnsignedByte, BlittableValueType.StrideOf(lineList.ToArray()), 16);

    GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Lines, lineVbo.NumElements, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
}
```

It worked well on my PC, but on other one DrawElements threw "memory violation access", that was likely bacause of use glEnableClientState (according to similar questions on SO).

I replaced it with new Draw(via shader, but actually I don't need any shader in my program):

```
 Shader.Bind(shader); //Shader is a helper class that works correctly
   GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, lineVbo.VboID);
   GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Double, false, BlittableValueType.StrideOf(lineList.ToArray()), 0);
   GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);

   GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 4, VertexAttribPointerType.UnsignedByte, false, BlittableValueType.StrideOf(lineList.ToArray()), 16);
   GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);

   GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, lineVbo.EboID);
   GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, lineVbo.NumElements, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, (IntPtr)0);
```

Fragment shader gives an error "ERROR: 29718:48252: '' : storage qualifier not valid with layout qualifier id" :

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 1) in vec4 fragmentColor;
out vec4 color;
void main(){
color = fragmentColor;
}
```

How can I overcome this error or replace EnableClientState in other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using OpenGL version 3.3, which uses GLSL v3.30. That's what you said in your fragment shader with `#version 330`.

`layout(location)` for the [*interface* between shader stages](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Program_separation_linkage) was not added until GLSL version 4.10. So you can't use it. 3.30 added `layout(location)` for the *outputs* of fragment shader, and the inputs of vertex shaders. That is, the top and bottom of the shader pipeline.

But not for the interfaces between shader stages. So remove the `layout(location)` designation.